# What's the intuition for strongly consistent estimator?

Tags: statistics

I'm working through a portion of my statistics notes. Weak and strong consistency of estimators is defined. While I can intuitively understand the meaning of weak consistency (wikipedia has a very nice graph at the top of this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator), I cannot picture anything when thinking about strong consistency. Is there any intuition for it?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the difference between convergence in probability and convergence almost surely. Almost sure convergence means that the events on which the estimate does not converge to the true value have probability 0. On the other hand, convergence in probability just means that the probability of deviation from the true value goes to 0 in the limit.

Comment: Good notes from CMU: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture4.pdf